# How do I access my audio streams so I can direct them to different audio outputs

Tags: java, c, audio, io, buffer

- Are **all** audio inputs assigned byte streams that run concurrently?

  - ie. a capture card(hardware), or a browser, streaming youtube(software)
- Are **all** enabled audio output devices assigned to read from unique buffers?

  - ie. hdmi out, speaker outputs on my audio card, speaker outputs on my case, speaker outputs on my motherboard ect..

Comment: you can use gstreamer with various plugin to solve what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alsa library for it in Linux
In Linux terms, audio hardware are unique ALSA devices in software term. The audio data to the alsa devices can be from unique buffers or a audio buffer can be send to 2 output alsa devices.

It is possible.

a.mp3  --> HDMI Out (unique buffer)

b.mp3 ---> speaker  (unique buffer)

a.mp3  --> HDMI Out  (common buffer)
a.mp3  --> Speaker Out